# I am having trouble understanding results from a line of code in the c++ for dummies book

Tags: c++, for-loop

This is the entire code:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int i, j, x; 

    for (x=0, i=0, j=10; i <= 5, j <= 20;  i++, j=j+2, cout<<i+j, x+=i+j)
    {

    }
    return 0;
}
```

This line specifically:

```
for (x=0, i=0, j=10; i <= 5, j <= 20;  i++, j=j+2, cout<<i+j, x+=i+j)
```

I understand what it does. There are two variables which increase at different rates which are both added to a single variable repeatedly. However, I don't understand why the result is so large. The result is 131619222528. (x=0). Aren't you adding something like 10+13+16... All the way up to 25? How can the result possibly be that large?

Comment: I added the entire code

Comment: `131619222528` is not a single number - it's several numbers printed together with no separator. Make it `cout<<i+j << ' '` to see what's going on.

Comment: Here's a hint: the result you see is not just a single number that was outputed.

Comment: Oh okay that makes so much more sense. C++ for dummies has an embarrassing number of errors -_-

Comment: @Sam Did you mistakenly pick up a copy of "C++ *by* Dummies"?

Answer (score 2):

You can divide the loop into 3 parts. Part A is the initialization of variables: x=0, i=0, j=10;
Part B is the condition that needs to be met for the loop to continue:
i <= 5, j <= 20;
Part C is the action taken AFTER the first iteration of the loop:
i++, j=j+2, cout<

So what happens is
loop 1: Nothing (the cout is in part C)
loop 2: i is incremented to 1, j is incremented to 12, cout i+j prints 13
loop 3: i is incremented to 2, j is incremented to 14, cout i+j prints 16
etc. etc. You get all those numbers in a line.

Comment: Also it's not a mistake. They're all in a line because there's no cout <<  <<endl. Since there's no endl in the code, they'll all print in a line. The output is correct